# typeMismatch: generic unknown type jsondecoder / codable / RxSwift

Tags: ios, swift, rx-swift, codable, jsondecoder

With map in RxSwift, for every character inserted in search bar, I call an API to get json and parse data to table view. But since I changed every character inserted into a constant API instead just for demo purpose, I've got this error 
fail at line: `let model: T = try JSONDecoder().decode(T.self, from: data ?? Data())`

please help me, thank you very much

> Binding error: typeMismatch(Swift.Array, Swift.DecodingError.Context(codingPath: [], debugDescription: "Expected to decode Array but found a dictionary instead.", underlyingError: nil))

[This's my codable struct for mapping with json given below](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hPU1W.png)

```
struct Result: Codable {
let shopName: String
let shopImage: String
let maintenanceDate: String
let maintenanceContent: String
let shopDetailUrl: String

private enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
    case shopName = "shop_name"
    case shopImage = "shop_image"
    case maintenanceDate = "maintenance_date"
    case maintenanceContent = "maintenance_content"
    case shopDetailUrl = "shop_detail_url"
}
```

}

```
struct ShopModel: Codable {
let status: Bool
let code: Int
let message: String?
let result: Result

private enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
    case status
    case code
    case message
    case result = "result"
}
```

}

[json data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/V5coE.png)

```
{
"status": true,
"code": 200,
"message": null,
"result": {
    "shop_name": "AAAAAA",
    "shop_image": "https://......",
    "maintenance_date": "",
    "maintenance_content": "",
    "shop_detail_url": "/store/detail/111113/42"
}
```

}

[This is where events triggered to call api everytime a character inserted in searchbar](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bzXXn.png)

```
    private func configureReactiveBinding() {
    searchController.searchBar.rx.text.asObservable()
        .map { _ in CarRequest(token: "6aa86866d95414a9e469f4323b1da139f96d22d8") }
        .flatMap { request -> Observable<[ShopModel]> in
            return self.apiClient.send(apiRequest: request)
        }
        .bind(to: tableView.rx.items(cellIdentifier: cellIdentifier)) { index, model, cell in
            cell.textLabel?.text = model.result.shopImage
            cell.detailTextLabel?.text = model.result.shopName
            cell.textLabel?.adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth = true
        }
        .disposed(by: disposeBag)
}
```

}

[send api request, and decode json](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Pgt3K.png)

```
    private let baseURL = URL(string: "https://stg.api.link-collabo.jp/api/user/myshop.json")!

func send<T: Codable>(apiRequest: APIRequest) -> Observable<T> {
    return Observable<T>.create { [unowned self] observer in
        let request = apiRequest.request(with: self.baseURL)
        let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request) { (data, response, error) in
            do {
                let model: T = try JSONDecoder().decode(T.self, from: data ?? Data())
                print(model)
                observer.onNext(model)
            } catch let error {

                observer.onError(error)
            }
            observer.onCompleted()
        }
        task.resume()

        return Disposables.create {
            task.cancel()
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. Please don't post images, post text. Nobody who is willing to help is willing to retype dozens of code lines.

Comment: I'm not familiar with RxSwift but the error is clear. It says the root object is a dictionary so replace `Observable<[ShopModel]>` with `Observable<ShopModel>` .

Comment: i've already tried, and got this error in xcode: [Ambiguous reference to member 'text' ]      at this line searchController.searchBar.rx.text.asObservable()